# -O2 compiler switch causing math error

Tags: compiler-optimization, gfortran

I am evaluating a computational electromagnetic modeling program that uses both C and Fortran for implementing a Longley-Rice propagation model. When compiled with no optimizations, I get one set of numerical results. When using the -O2 switch to enable some basic performance improvements, some of the results change slightly from the results using no optimization.

This is the case whether or not the -fno-unsafe-math-optimizations switch is set explicitly (although it is the default for GNU compilers)

Anyone know what could cause basic optimizations to cause math error when they're supposed to maintain strict adherence to IEEE FP rules?

Comment: Without a minimal example to look at it's hard to say. A guess would be that the representation of some constants in a complex expression is changing, but that's pure speculation.

Comment: do you have any uninitialized values in your program?

Comment: I have gone through the code and eliminated the uninitialized variables that the compiler warned about (by initializing them), yet the output still remains different with the -O2 switch enabled. The source code can be downloaded from the FCC - just google "FCC OET-69" and you can find it that way, if anyone cares that much :)

Comment: without an explicit code fragment (sorry, I'm not going to google it), it's hard to say anything better than: make sure you have implicit nones everywhere, crank all the compiler warnings up the maximum level, cross the fingers. If the problem is still there, it's possible some algorithm somewhere is not stable enough.

Comment: Look at http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html for what switches the 02 switch toggle.Switch them individually and see which one cause your false results.This might give you a hint